# error loading table on bigquery dashboard but queries works fine

Tags: google-bigquery

I clicked a table on bigquery dashboard, got this error:

[image: error message]

However, I can get data when I do a `select` on this table. (That means the table does exist)

I already have the highest admin privilege so it shouldn't be a permission issue.

I created this table with python script, which collects data, writes into a csv file, and upload the csv file to bigquery everyday. After I created the table I once changed the schema both in the script and on the dashboard. Not sure if that's the cause, but the table loading error occurred several days after I changed the schema.

Comment: If you try to fetch the table data using [Tables.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) api do you get the same error?

Comment: @TamirKlein I tried bigquery.Client in the python library, the `get_table` it provides works without errors.

Comment: If you can't see the table schema and info in BigQuery WebUI old and new with the correct user and you are able to get it via Python code than I suggest you open a support ticket with Google directly.

Comment: @TamirKlein OK, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Do you have any addblock extension in your browser by any chance?, if so, try disabling it and try again.

Comment: @F10 Thanks! It works now!

Comment: Cool, I'm posting this as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Addblock extensions, this might be the root cause of this issue. Thus, try disabling it, then try running your query again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you really wanna keep AdBlock on, just make sure none of your tables contain the word "ads". Apparently that's what triggers AdBlock to block you from being able to open it.